# Saving Tiff with specific Tiff Tags using PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am trying to save a TIFF image using PIL with custom tags.

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
numrows=10
numcols=10
data = np.random.randint(0, 255, (numrows,numcols)).astype(np.uint8)

rawtiff=PIL.Image.fromarray(data)

custtifftags={'Photometric':1, 'Compression':1, 'BitsPerSample':32,\
              'SamplePerPixel':1, 'SampleFormat':3,'ImageLength':10,\
              'ImageWidth':10, 'PlanarConfiguration':1, 'ResolutionUnit':2}

rawtiff.save('test.tiff', tiffinfo=custtifftags)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

What is causing this error and how can I save images using PIL while setting my own tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  You need to format the TIFF tags as follows:

```
custtifftags={262:(1,), 259:(0,), 258:(32,),\
              277:(1,), 339:(3,),257:(10,),\
              256:(10,), 284:(1,), 296:(2,)}
```

Answer (score 3):

TIFF doesn't define tags by name, numeric values only.
Alphabetic names being for convenience.
In TiffTags you can find alphabetic values which use in PIL.

As solution you can try:

```
from PIL.TiffImagePlugin import ImageFileDirectory_v2
custtifftags = ImageFileDirectory_v2()
custtifftags[101] = 'Test Data 101'
```